# RDPClip is not launching when I use Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

When I'm using remote desktop to connect to my PC from my laptop(both running Windows 7 ultimate), RDPClip.exe never gets started. I can run it manually and copy/paste will work just fine, but I have no idea why it won't start automatically.

I've done the usual of making sure the "Drives" checkbox is checked, but other than that I have no idea why it's mad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that you're using the latest [Remote Desktop Connection 7.0 client update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084).
Even if you're using the latest version, re-installing the RDP client and rebooting might help.

Verify that rdpclip.exe is in its right place : `C:\Windows\System32\rdpclip.exe`.

Also verify that the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\Wds\rdpwd` contains the right entry for `StartupPrograms`. It should contain "rdpclip", but you can also try the full path "C:\Windows\System32\rdpclip.exe".

The last-ditch solution, used when no better one is found, is to use a .bat file that contains:

```
Taskkill.exe /im rdpclip.exe
Rdpclip.exe
```

Some people even added this script as a startup item, and [report](http://www.minasi.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=8698) that this solved the problem (after reboot).

Comment: Thanks for this. For some reason the registry entry for StartupPrograms had no value in it. That fixed it!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that this doesn't fix it in all cases. In my computer everything is fine (also checked this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/is/winserverTS/thread/d92ad1c3-826f-496b-8145-bb31615c55fe) and still cant set it up to start automatically. If I start rpdclip manually everything is fine.

Comment: @Odys: I need more info on your computer, so possibly you could start a post of your own with info such as OS and patch-level. Just to remark that if you installed optional [Windows Update 2592687 (RDP 8)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2592687), I had troubles with it and had to uninstall it.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for replying. That helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

That's weird. :)

One place to check is the registry key (on the machine you are trying to RDP TO) `HKey_Local_Machine\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\Winstations\RDP-Tcp\fDisableClip`

Ensure it's set to `0` -- If `fDisableClip` is set to `1` then `rdpclip.exe` won't run.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I checked this and it's already set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

On the remote desktop client click the options button and go to local resources and make sure that the clipboard option is checked before initiating the connection.